# RxJava: how to do a second api call if first is successful and then create a combinded response

Tags: rx-java2, micronaut

This is what I want to do:

1. call first rest API
2. if first succeeds call seconds rest API
3. if both are successful -> create an aggregated response

I'm using RxJava2 in Micronaut.

This is what I have but I'm not sure it's correct. What would happen if the first or second API call fails?

```
@Singleton
public class SomeService {
    private final FirstRestApi firstRestApi;
    private final SecondRestApi secondRestApi;

    public SomeService(FirstRestApi firstRestApi, SecondRestApi secondRestApi) {
        this.firstRestApi = firstRestApi;
        this.secondRestApi = secondRestApi;
    }

    public Single<AggregatedResponse> login(String data) {
        Single<FirstResponse> firstResponse = firstRestApi.call(data);
        Single<SecondResponse> secondResponse = secondRestApi.call();
        return firstResponse.zipWith(secondResponse, this::convertResponse);
    }

    private AggregatedResponse convertResponse(FirstResponse firstResponse, SecondResponse secondResponse) {
        return AggregatedResponse
                   .builder()
                   .something1(firstResponse.getSomething1())
                   .something2(secondResponse.getSomething2())
                   .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is ok, if one of the two requests fails the zip will fail too. If in the other hand you want to use the result of the first api call in the second call then you have to use concatMap operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as

```
public Single<AggregatedResponse> login(String data) {
    return firstRestApi.call(data)
             .flatMap((firstResponse) -> secondRestApi.call().map((secondResponse) -> {
                 return Pair.create(firstResponse, secondResponse);
             })
             .map((pair) -> {
                 return convertResponse(pair.getFirst(), pair.getSecond());
             });
}
```

In which case you no longer need `zipWith`. Errors just go to error stream as usual.

Comment: I wonder how would you do it if the first one is failed or if a condition is used